# ORACLE sql hours between two timestamps format

Tags: database, oracle

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE B(
...
date1 TIMESTAMP(6),
date2 TIMESTAMP(6),
...);
```

and I want to get hours between two timestamps. So I run query:

```
SELECT (date1 - date2)*24 from B;
```

Result looks like this: +000000024 00:00:00.000000 but I want something like 24:00. How I can format the query? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a subquery to extract the hours from the expression

```
SELECT  extract( hour from x) hours FROM
(SELECT (date1 - date2)x FROM B)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT to_char((date1 - date2)*24,'HH24:MI') from B;
```